# How to handle regex in BeautifulSoup / CSS selector?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm looking for a solution to use regex in `BeautifulSoup` to find elements that may contain the text `HO #` with possible spaces and ignoring case sensitivity.

```
check_ho_number3 = soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("HO #")+ td')
print(check_ho_number3)
```

How can I integrate my existing regex expression into `soup.select_one()`?

```
check_regex = re.compile("HO\s?#",re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: so you want "HO #" or "ho #"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSS SELECTORS` only supports [CSS syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) but you can search by tag content with the [`string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) property:

```
soup.find(string=re.compile(r"HO\s?#",re.IGNORECASE))
soup.find_all(string=re.compile(r"HO\s?#",re.IGNORECASE))
```

To `findNextSibling('td')` step back to the `parent` of your located object.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup('<table><tr><td>HO #</td><td>I am the next sibling</td></tr><tr><td>HO #</td></tr><tr><td>ho#</td><td>I am the next sibling</td></tr></table>')

for e in soup.find_all(string=re.compile(r"HO\s?#",re.IGNORECASE)):
    print(e)
    print(e.parent.findNextSibling('td'))
```

---

```
HO #
<td>I am the next sibling</td>
HO #
None
ho#
<td>I am the next sibling</td>
```